# What does this symbol mean when describing a probability density function?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, notation

Whilst studying some probability and statistics, I have came across $P_X(x)$ and $P(X=x)$ but I am struggling to understanding what the following means:

$P(r ; \theta)$

I read it as "The probability of the random variable $r$ with respect to $\theta$" but what is this $\theta$? I understand it is a parameter but is this parameter similar to what a variable is in an equation?

Comment: What do you mean by "with respect to"? I hope you weren't referring to a conditional probability distribution; that would use $|$, not $;$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually $\theta$ is a parameter of the distribution. Often this parameter represent an indicator of the law.

**Example 1**

$$P_X(x;\theta)=\frac{e^{-\theta}\theta^{x}}{x!}$$

$x=0,1,2,3,...$

$X$ is a Poisson with mean $\theta$

Often you can find the symbol

$P(r|\theta)$ which better specify that $\theta$ is just a parameter and not a variable.

Sometimes a probability law can be viewed as a function with respect to the variable or to the parameter,

**Example 2**

$$L(\mathbf{x},\theta) \propto \theta^{\Sigma x}(1-\theta)^{n-\Sigma x}$$

This is a likelihood of a bernulli random sample $(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)$ with parameter $\theta \in [0;1]$ but it can also be viewed as a Beta density in the variable $\theta$ (with $\theta \in [0;1]$ support) and parameters $Beta[(\Sigma x+1);(n-\Sigma x+1)]$

This depends on the context you are facing.